# How to assign a value to an index of a three dimensional array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have defined two three dimensional arrays as:

```
int[, ,] Link_k = new int[length1, length1, length1];
int[][][] Link_k2 = new int[length1][][];
```

where `length1` is variable and could be any integer number.

My question is that how could I assign a value for a special index or for all first indices. I tried

```
Link_k.SetValue(-1,(0,,));
Link_k2.SetValue(-1,[0][][]);
```

But that does not compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Patrick Hofman said, Link_k is pretty easy:

```
Link_k[x, y, 0] = -1;
```

Or, using `SetValue`:

```
Link_k.SetValue( -1, x, y, 0 );
```

However, you don't actually create a three dimensional array for `Link_k2` - you create a one dimensional array of arrays of arrays. E.g. `Link_k2[0]` is `int[][]`, and, when it is initialised, `Link_k2[0][0]` is `int[]`.

So, for `Link_k2` you'd need to:

```
for (int x = 0; x < Link_k2.Length; x++)
{
    //create a new array of arrays at Link_k2[x]
    Link_k2[x] = new int[length1][];
    for (int y = 0; y < Link_k2[x].Length; y++)
    {
        //create a new arrays at Link_k2[x][y]
        Link_k2[x][y] = new int[length1];
        for (int z = 0; z < Link_k2[x][y].Length; z++)
        {
            Link_k2[x][y][z] = -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you think `Link_k.SetValue( -1, x, y, 0 );` does not mean a three dimensional array?

Comment: @Royeh - I don't quite understand your question. `Link_k` is `int[,,]`, and I wanted to highlight that you can use either the indexer - `[x,y,z]` - or `SetValue(val, x,y,z)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the first index of every Z-axis array, you have to iterate over it, using `for` for example.

For `Link_k`:

```
for (int x = 0; x < Array.GetUpperBound(Link_k, 0); x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; i < Array.GetUpperBound(Link_k, 1); y++)
    {
        Link_k[x, y, 0] = -1;
    }
}
```

And for `Link_k2`:

```
int[][][] Link_k2 = new int[length1][][];

for (int x = 0; x < Link_k2.Length; x++)
{
    Link_k2[x] = new int[length1][];
    for (int y = 0; i < Link_k2[x].Length; y++)
    {
        Link_k2[x][y] = new int[length1];
        Link_k2[x][y][0] = -1;
    }
}
```

(Note you don't seem to assign the second and third array. Assign that in a `for` loop, so you assign every array in every array, etc. so I have put that in too)

Comment: Yeah, but you need to do that for every value of `x` and `y`, not just `0`.